# Determine the minimum number of coins required for giving a change using greedy approach

Tags: c, greedy

As an assignment for my course on Design and Analysis of Algorithms, I was asked to determine the minimum number of coins required for giving a change, using a greedy approach. I came up with this intuitive approach:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int hundreds=0,tens=0,ones=0,sum=0;

  printf("Enter a sum of money in range 1 to 999\n");
  scanf("%d",&sum);
  while(sum!=0) {
    if (sum<10&&sum>=1){
      ones=sum/1;
      sum-=ones;
    }
    else if(sum>=10&&sum<100){
      tens=sum/10;
      sum-=tens*10;
    }
    else if(sum>=100&&sum<=999){
      hundreds=sum/100;
      sum-=hundreds*100;
    }
    else{
      printf("Error");
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  printf("%d $100, %d $10, %d $1",hundreds,tens,ones);
  return 0;
}
```

Is this approach greedy? 
How do I prove that the program is correct and uses the greedy approach?

Comment: Who told you to use a greedy approach? Did you ask them what they mean by 'a greedy approach'?

Comment: This can be solved without a loop; in each iteration, exactly 1 of the cases will be true, and will never be true in any future iteration.

Comment: While the compiler doesn't care about spaces, empty lines, indentation or comments, those things are very important to humans attempting to read and understand your code.

Comment: By 'a greedy approach' I mean a greedy algorithm. So is this program using a greedy algorithm? How do I prove it?

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma there is no limit on the greedy because it is possible to add any useless computation, but it is easily possible to do more greedy, look my answer

Comment: Since the question is about the minimum number of coins. Are we discussing English pounds or American coins or something else?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d",&sum);`  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed greedy approach but you need to reverse the order of if-then-else. In general, *greedy* means to consume at the current moment the biggest quantity that you can consume.

You need to check first for the biggest coin.  There is no need for while-loop.

```
if(sum>=100) {
  hundreds=sum/100;
  sum-=hundreds*100;
}
if(sum>=10){
  tens=sum/10;
  sum-=tens*10;
} 
ones = sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not enough greedy because it can be worst :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int hundreds=0,tens=0,ones=0,sum=0;

  printf("Enter a sum of money in range 1 to 999\n");
  if ((scanf("%d",&sum) == 1) && (sum >= 1) && (sum <= 999)) {
    while(sum!=0) {
      if (sum<10&&sum>=1){
        ones += 1;
        sum -= 1;
      }
      else if(sum>=10&&sum<100){
        tens += 1;
        sum -= 10;
      }
      else if(sum>=100&&sum<=999){
        hundreds += 1;
        sum -= 100;
      }
      else{ /* impossible case in fact */
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
      }
    }

    printf("%d $100, %d $10, %d $1\n",hundreds,tens,ones);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra g.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a sum of money in range 1 to 999
997
9 $100, 9 $10, 7 $1
```

---

> How do I prove that the program is correct

A (greedy) way to prove the code is correct is to use the brutal force to check all from result from 1 to 999 :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int n;

  for (n = 1; n <= 999; ++n) {
    /* the algo */
    int hundreds=0,tens=0,ones=0, sum = n;

    while(sum!=0) {
      if (sum<10&&sum>=1){
        ones += 1;
        sum -= 1;
      }
      else if(sum>=10&&sum<100){
        tens += 1;
        sum -= 10;
      }
      else if(sum>=100&&sum<=999){
        hundreds += 1;
        sum -= 100;
      }
      else{ /* impossible case in fact */
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
      }
    }

    /* check */
    if ((hundreds*100 + tens*10 + ones) != n) {
      printf("error for %d : %d $100, %d $10, %d $1\n",n, hundreds,tens,ones);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  puts("all ok");
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra g.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
all ok
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's questions?

Comment: @JeffUK answer corrected to do more greedy ... damned

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not include header files those contents are not used
3. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
4. performs the desired functionality
5. performs appropriate error checking
6. performs a 'greedy' algorithm of consuming as much of the 'money' as quickly as possible, using the least number of 'bills'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main( void )
{
    int sum;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a sum of money in range 1 to 999\n");
        if( scanf("%d",&sum) != 1)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n");
            return -1;
        }       
    } while( sum<0 || sum>999 );

    int hundreds = sum/100;
    sum          = sum % 100;
    int tens     = sum/10;
    sum          = sum % 10;
    int ones     = sum;

    printf("%d $100, %d $10, %d $1\n",hundreds,tens,ones);
}
```

The proposed code ignores the (American) bills $50, $20, $5, and $2